# blender 2.93 in material property bottom Assign material doesn't show

Tags: materials, interface

I try to assign the second material to the mesh in Edit Mode, with the applied faces selected, but bottoms Assign, Select, Deselect were gone... :(
Although a previosly saved copy of the same fale works fine.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It sounds like you are in object mode - you need to be in edit mode for those options to be visible.

Comment: Hi Christofer, of course I'm in Edit Mode

Comment: I solwed the problem as follows, I created a new Layout, and evrything works fine.

Comment: But I'm still wondering for the future, what was wrong with the previos Layout?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Clemente, I attache the problem file below. You can see in Landscape001 leyer something is wrong there. You can't change, o apply the materials.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/fdc63567dae84580a08bd199ef4ea0a7